# New at Eclipse using PHP and needing tips

Tags: eclipse, phpeclipse

I´m switching from DW to eclipse (actually I´m still in doubt on cahnging to netbeans) because heard good thing about it and also because I´m going to turn to linux asap. Well I´m still in Wind 7 64bits, just to get used to eclipse, I downloaded it, but saw this: it created a folder called .settings and two files called buildpath and .project. As I used DW it also created _notes which I always hated it and also disabled it. How can this be possible in eclipse and are they useful, what for?.

Also if someone could recommend me a great eclipse tutorial, would be great, I´m kind of liking it´s enviornment, but need to get more documentation about this.

Thanks to everyone who contributes with this, might help others as well (well stackoverflow is very helpfull for me a while ago)

:)

Answer (score 0):

First define the purpose, why you don't need these files.
If you are using cvs-system for code you can add these files to ignore.

BTW, these files are useful, because:

*.project* - defines project-specific properties that override workspace-specific and global properties

*buildpath* - defines what libraries will be included in your project.

Also, both of these files useful when you share your project. In that way everyone who using eclipse can import your project and get all your properties.

P.S. Simple eclipse tutorial can be found [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html).

Comment: WOW!!, thanks for your answer, is really helpful. Apreciate it. Ok have some things to keep asking: you said "If you are using cvs-system for code you can add these files to ignore" how, and the other question by ignorance and apreciate your help is: cvs-system, never used before, I´m freelance and do things alone, but I guess this could be a very helpful tool right?, can you give me more instructions, what is it for, how t use, is it client side or server side, etc. Thanks apreciate you help again